# Not able to access Kendo datasource in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, kendo-grid, datasource

I am very new in `Kendo` UI binding My scenario is I have bind grid using `kendo` and data is showing to me but when I am trying to access `datasource` in `jquery` it giving me error which says:

> Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined

**below is MVC View code:**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Buck.TaskNet.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.GetMembers>()
.Name("MemberGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Width(15).Title("SL NO").Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ClientID).Title("CLIENT ID").Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Title("LAST NAME").Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("FIRST NAME").Filterable(false);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.Filterable(ftp => ftp.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(10)
.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
.Read(read => read.Action("GetMembers", "Dashboard"))
.ServerOperation(false)
     )
                    )
```

**Js code here:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fName").keyup(function () {
            var value = $("#fName").val();
            var grid = $("#MemberGrid").data("kendoGrid"); //undefined
            debugger;
            if (value) {
                grid.dataSource.filter({ field: "FirstName", operator: "contains", value: value });
            } else {
                grid.dataSource.filter({});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**here Html Code:**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label class="col-form-label" for="fName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName">
                        </div>
```

On `keyup` function want to get grid `datasource` for apply custom filter but not able to get `datasource` Please check the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Is your grid inside a modal? And do you load the modal dynamically? Can you even get to `$("#MemberGrid")`? If you can, that'd suggest the Kendo UI Libraries aren't loaded.

Comment: Yeah I can get $("#MemberGrid") on JS. But I can see libraries on page. :(

Comment: In which order do you load them? Try loading jQuery followed by kendo.all.min.js first and see if that works. I suspect your issue is the order you load the files in. I could be wrong. I've never came across anything similar unless you dynamically loaded the grid.